# Removing of records matching filter criteria in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

How can I remove the records from ag-grid which are matching a certain filter criteria? I have tried to pass objects with filter criteria for transactional update of ag-grid but still no luck.

Comment: See [ask], and especially [mcve]. The idea is you describe what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you get. reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method [`api.selectAllFiltered`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/#selection) to get filtered rows and then delete it

```
let filteredData = this.gridApi.selectAllFiltered();
this.gridApi.updateRowData({ remove: filteredData });
```